# What is the most optimal way (processing wise) to combine two BigQuery queries?

Tags: google-bigquery

I have two valid queries that I need to combine to produce iOS and Android results in the same table. I tried 'UNION ALL' and this will process 217 GB (shown below). I think I could get by with the data I need if I omit selecting the fields h.eventInfo.eventCategory and 
  h.eventinfo.eventaction, however this only reduces the amount processed to 177 GB. What is the best way to optimize a query like this?

```
SELECT
  date,
  'iOS' as app_source,
  h.eventInfo.eventCategory,
  h.eventinfo.eventaction,
  h.eventinfo.eventlabel,
  COUNT(1) events,
  COUNT(DISTINCT CONCAT(fullvisitorid, CAST(visitstarttime AS string))) uniqueEvents
FROM
   `xxxx.ga_sessions_*`,
  UNNEST(hits) h
WHERE
  h.type='EVENT'
  and (h.eventInfo.eventCategory = 'Live' and h.eventInfo.eventLabel = 'Team Chat')
  or (h.eventInfo.eventCategory = 'Messages' and h.eventInfo.eventLabel = 'Direct Message')
  and date >= "20190801"
GROUP BY
  1,2,3,4,5
  ORDER BY
  date

union all

SELECT
 date,
  'Android' as app_source,
  h.eventInfo.eventCategory,
  h.eventinfo.eventaction,
  h.eventinfo.eventlabel,
  COUNT(1) events,
  COUNT(DISTINCT CONCAT(fullvisitorid, CAST(visitstarttime AS string))) uniqueEvents
FROM
   `xxxx.ga_sessions_*`,
  UNNEST(hits) h
WHERE
  h.type='EVENT'
  and (h.eventInfo.eventCategory = 'Live' and h.eventInfo.eventLabel = 'Team Chat')
  or (h.eventInfo.eventCategory = 'Messages' and h.eventInfo.eventLabel = 'Direct Message')
  and date >= "20190801"
GROUP BY
  1,2,3,4,5
  ORDER BY
  date
```

Comment: those two queries are exactly the same  - what makes first one iOs and second one Android specific rather than first column?

Comment: They are querying two different tables - one iOS and one Android.

Comment: oh, i see. so in this case it is not clear what are you asking for! `UNION ALL` is th way to go and you already have it!

Comment: First because you are querying multiple tables using the wildcard * it may well be normal that you are scanning (processing shards) on lots of data! Second I noticed that for both queries you are hitting the same tables, why not instead use a WHERE predicate ->  WHERE app_source in ('iOS', 'Android)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `date >= '20190801'`, you should use `_TABLE_SUFFIX >= '20190801'`.  You have a sharded table and are using the wildcard `*`.  The `_TABLE_SUFFIX` serves to filter your shards.  Note, I am assuming date belongs to the session, and not the nested hit.

[Querying multiple tables using a wildcard table](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/querying-wildcard-tables)